# Can I use Sessions with Firebase JWT Token on Laravel to further optimise my API requests?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, jwt

I'm using Firebase Auth to manage the authentication & using the JWT Token to communicate with my backend Laravel App.

```
//eg: example.com/home.html

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        user.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ false).then(function(idToken) {
            storeToken(idToken);
            ajaxCallTest1();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle error
        });
    }
})


//Laravel
//eg: api.example.com/*

function test1(){
    $firebaseUser = $this->decodeToken($jwtToken_fromFrontend);
    $user = User::where('uid', '=', $firebaseUser->uid)->first();

    //retrieve $user object from Laravel
    //and using the object to process other logic eg: edit profile, grab products & more...
}
```

base on above example/flow:

1. Every request I make I'll need to pass the JWT token to backend
2. Backend validate token
3. If Token valid, grab user where uid = firebase->uid
4. using the matched object and proceed other logic

will it too expensive to validate JWT & retrieve user data on every call? May I know is it a better way to work on this, I'm wondering if we can set $_SESSION to skip the #3 process? like below:

```
//Laravel
//eg: api.example.com/*
function test1(){
    if(!isSet($_SESSION['userData']))
    {
        $firebaseUser = $this->decodeToken($jwtToken_fromFrontend);
        $user = User::where('uid', '=', $firebaseUser->uid)->first();
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $user;
    }

    // using $_SESSION['userData'] to process other items
    // so that we can skip 'validate & retrieve $user' steps on our next call
}
```

With above method, if we're retrieving data directly from `$_SESSION`, we don't need to run queries on every API call, may I know is this a proper way to manage? or is there any way to further optimise and make it with Firebase Auth & Laravel?

thanks!

Comment: This kinda goes against the point of stateless APIs. In you example, if User A accesses your API with their token, and you store it, then User B would get User A's details when they access it, and so on. The reason the token is sent and decoded on every request is to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this, I'm still in the midst of exploring & researching.

So it's consider normal to decode and retrieve data on every API request & it's consider a bad practice/impossible to achieve with my $_SESSION method correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You got it :) The reason the token is sent and decoded is so your API knows who is calling it. If you store the decoded result in `session()` (which typically isn't actually available for API routes in Laravel), then the server thinks that every request it receives is from that user, even if the token being sent would prove otherwise when decoded. The decoding/querying process is pretty light, since it's only looking for a single record in your database, and if index properly, can be quite quick.

Comment: ... continued. Caching can be used if you need to load a lot of information related to that user, but the cache key would need to be unique to the queried user, such as `cache()->put('user_'.$user->id.'_details', $userDetails);`, etc. But actually determining which user to use should be done on each request.

Comment: Thank you sir @TimLewis, appreciate much!